# Calling functions in a class in Python

Tags: python

Suppose that I have the following in a single `.py` file:

```
class Graph( object ):
    def ReadGraph( file_name ):

def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
    g=ReadGraph(file_name)
```

where `ProcessGraph` is a driver class.  When I type

```
ProcessGraph('testcase.txt', verbose=True)
```

I get this error

```
NameError: global name 'ReadGraph' is not defined
```

Could someone explain how to fix this error?

Comment: `ReadGraph()` is a method of the `Graph` class. You need an instance of `Graph` in order to call it.

Comment: I doubt very much you need classes here at all. Python is not Java.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Graph( object ):
    def ReadGraph( file_name ):
        # do something
        pass

def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
    g = Graph()
    return g.ReadGraph(file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReadGraph` is in the namespace of the `Graph` class, which is why you can't call it as a high-level function. Try this:

```
class Graph(object):
     @classmethod
     def ReadGraph(cls, file_name):
         # Something

def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
     g=Graph.ReadGraph(file_name)
```

The [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator will let you call `ReadGraph` on a class without creating a class instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just decorate them with @staticmethod

```
class Graph( object ):
    @staticmethod
    def ReadGraph( file_name ):
         print 'read graph'

    @staticmethod
    def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
         g=ReadGraph(file_name)

if __name__=="__main__":
    Graph.ProcessGraph('f', 't')
```

Outputs 'hello'.

[staticmethod vs classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

create a instance of Graph class.

```
class Graph(object):
    def ReadGraph(file_name):
        pass
```

```
def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
    g = Graph()
    out = g.ReaGraph(file_name)
    print out
```